# Include Value From Previous Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm using SQL Server here. I have a table for inventory where only January has a beginning quantity. Each row has a changed quantity for that month.

So..

```
Item | Month | Beg | PerChg
---------------------------
001    1       5      5
001    2       0     -1
001    3       0      4
```

So in the above case, January would be 10, February 9, and March 13, and so on...

Is it possible to take care of this line by line in SQL?

I looked into lag briefly but I'm not so sure it does what I need or if it's the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were on the right track with the **window functions**, however, **Lag()** would not be much help here.  The good news is you can use **sum() over**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Item] varchar(50),[Month] int,[Beg] int,[PerChg] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('001',1,5,5)
,('001',2,0,-1)
,('001',3,0,4)

Select * 
      ,RunningTotal = sum(Beg+PerChg) over (Partition By Item Order by Month)
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Item    Month   Beg     PerChg  RunningTotal
001     1       5       5       10
001     2       0       -1      9
001     3       0       4       13
```

Comment: @JeffMcClain Happy to help